# Flow chart for Reduced canonical form

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I am learning Reduced Canonical Form (RCF) of a fuzzy game and tried to summarize my understanding using the flow chart. Does the following correcting represent it?

Thank you!

Part 1:

```
Define the fuzzy game as {GL | GR}.

Introduce fuzzy games and left/right stops.

Is G an infinitesimal?
    Yes:
        Define LS(G) and RS(G).
        Check LS(G) and RS(G) both zero?
            Yes: Define G as an infinitesimal.
            No: Continue to Part 2.
    No: Continue to Part 2.
```

Part 2:

```
Introduce canonical form and reduced canonical form.

Check dominated options or reversible moves in G?
    Yes: Transform G to its reduced canonical form.
    No: G is already in canonical form.

Illustrate Example.

End.
```